# My react code works fine when loaded for the first time but it shows an error when the page is reloaded

Tags: reactjs

The first time I run the code it fetches the data fine.  But after refreshing an error occurs.

I am using react and node.js with a mongoDB for my backend. Is it because the component is unmounting when refreshed

**This is my app.js file**

```
import './App.css';
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

const App=()=> {
  const [items,setItems]=useState([]);
  
  
  // Request data using useEffeect
  useEffect(()=>
  {
    fetch("http://localhost:4000/items/get")
    .then(response=>response.json())
    .then(data=>setItems(data));
    
  },[])
  

  const showPizza=()=>
  {
    console.log("show Pizza");
    
  }
  const showBurger=()=>
  {
    console.log("show Burger");
    
  }
  console.log(items && items[0].result[0].image);
  return (
    <>
    <div className="home">
      <div className="pizza">
          <img src={items[0].result[0].image} alt="Pizza" onClick={showPizza}/>
      </div>
      <div className="burger">
          <img src={items[0].result[1].image} alt="Pizza" onClick={showBurger}/>
      </div>
    </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When i run the code for the first time, i got the two images displayed but when i refresh the page, the following error is shown in the console.
**This is the error**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'result' of undefined
    at App (App.js:48)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14985)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17811)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19049)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22776)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22707)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:22670)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:22293)
    at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:21881)
    at updateContainer (react-dom.development.js:25482)
    at react-dom.development.js:26021
    at unbatchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:22431)
    at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (react-dom.development.js:26020)
    at Object.render (react-dom.development.js:26103)
    at Module.<anonymous> (index.js:7)
    at Module../src/index.js (index.js:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:856)
    at fn (bootstrap:150)
    at Object.1 (reportWebVitals.js:14)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:856)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
    at main.chunk.js:1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're not persisting any state in the frontend of your app. The problem is probably coming from the backend. I'd recommend you use the chrome developer tools, go to the Network tab and find out what's the response you're getting on the second attempt. You will probably find the data is different.